# how to use searchController with two arrays

Tags: iphone, ios

I have `two arrays` (first names, Last names) in my `TableView` (`cell.textLabel` and `cell.detailTextLabel`)
I want to make a search bar in this `TableView`.
I have created class with two string.

```
@interface clientContent : NSObject { }
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *clName;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *clLast;
@end
```

then I have created array in main class (which have Table view) and added my information
like this

```
    for (int i = 0; i < PQntuples(clientQuery); i++)
{
    clientContent *cc = [[clientContent alloc] init];
    cc.clName = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:PQgetvalue(clientQuery, i, 0)];
    cc.clLast = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:PQgetvalue(clientQuery, i, 1)];
    [allClients addObject:cc];
}
```

after this I load it into `tableView`;

```
clientContent *cc = [allClients objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = cc.clName;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = cc.clLast;
}
```

Then I use

```
-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
```

How to make it right? I can't understand..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should override searchDisplayController:shouldReloadTableForSearchString: delegate method of UISearchDisplayController and filter datasource array for searchResultsTableView as you want.

You can apply predicate on your array(array of clientContent object) and change dataSource array. Using predicate you can filter your array on both fields(clName & clLast).

You can get help related to predicates from https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPredicate_Class/Reference/NSPredicate.html